# AWS glue with MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, mongodb-atlas

I've tried multiple things to try to connect AWS glue to MongoDB atlas. Has someone been successful in doing so and if so, please can someone help me with the steps.
The AWS documentation claims that it should work with any compatible MongoDB link but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am facing a similar issue. I checked with the AWS support team and it seems like they have a huge backlog of similar issues where customers have requested the ability to connect to MongoDB Atlas. Unfortunately, they don't have an ETA for this.

Either you can opt to migrate to AWS Document DB and then use Glue to crawl your data store or you probably have to think of some other way to get your data from atlas to a layer that is supported properly by Glue.